# FileTransfer "Saved file:" followed by FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, cordova

My app downloads a zip file from a remote webserver, then extracts it.

The javascript successfully calls FileTransfer, which logs:

```
FileTransfer Saved file: file:///data/data/com.yadda.yadda/update.zip
```

As part of the success function, javascript calls my custom update plugin which immediately tests for the file:

```
Context ctx = this.cordova.getActivity().getBaseContext();
File update = new File(ctx.getFilesDir(),"update.zip");
if(!update.exists()) Log.w("File not found",update.getAbsolutePath());
```

The log for that last line is:

```
File Not Found /data/data/com.yadda.yadda/update.zip
```

Later in a try/catch block I have an InputStream variable created and one of the catch blocks is a FileNotFoundException which is firing every time.

Begin edit - more info

The FileNotFoundException has an interesting bit.  The file path is wrong - even though I'm sending the same "update" variable to create the FileInputStream

```
InputStream fileis = new FileInputStream(update);
```

And the interesting bit of the exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.yadda.yadda/files/update.zip
```

End edit

What is going wrong here?  Cordova logs that the file transfer completed and the file was saved, but then the file doesn't exist when I test for it!  When I create the FileInputStream, why is the path different, causing the exception?

What am I missing?  Everything works fine in the IOS version of the app.

Edit 2: per request, I browsed the device filesystem and found that update.zip does indeed exist in /data/user/0/com.yadda.yadda

Comment: You show how you test for the file location, but not how you set the save file location in the first instance.  It seems clear to me that `getFilesDir()`, which is returning the correct location, is not where you saved the file, which again is clear from the file transfer log.  How did you set this - `///data/data/com.yadda.yadda/update.zip`?

Comment: What has javascript to do with your app? After you downloaded the zip what does Filetransfer has to do? You mention two different paths.

Comment: To be clear, `/data/data/com.yadda.yadda/files/` is the correct location which `getFilesDir()` returns.  Therefore, the problem is in the file transfer, which you have not shown us.  Therefore, it is not possible to answer your question.  To put it another way, `//data/data/com.yadda.yadda/` is not the correct place to store your files.

Comment: @simon, getFilesDir() is returning "/data/data/com.yadda.yadda", and the first Log.w shows that in the path returned by update..getAbsolutePath().

Comment: @simon, I'll manage the question, thank you.  The log output by FileTransfer (the cordova plugin generates the first log, not me) shows the path where the file was saved.  My Log.w (the second log displayed above) shows the path where I'm searching for the file - note that they are the same path.
The FileNotFoundException is generated when I attempt to use the same File variable to create an InputStream - and it shows the wrong path which is irrelevant at this point because the first two paths found in the logs match.

Comment: Yep, I got them the wrong way round and too late to edit the comment.  My point stands though.  I would also use the IDE file explorer to see what's going on.  What is that file transfer doing?  It might even be that the paths are correct but you are trying to test the file before it has been fully written and closed?

Comment: @greenapps - javascript initiates the FileTransfer.  FileNotFoundException references a path different than the path I passed to the InputStream which generates the exception.

Comment: @simon, the logs show "file saved" before my update.exists() test outputs the "File Not Found" log.

Comment: Jeez, I'm too tired.  Got to stop posting.  Now I get it.  The question boils down to, where did `/files/` come from?  Sorry, I'm not usually that slow ;).  I know it sounds crazy, but check the return of getAbsolutePath() in your catch.  Is it still the same?  I am having a hard time believing that the constructor for InputStream could have such a major bug.

Comment: @simon, That's sort of the issue - it's at least one of them.  But I'm concerned why the paths are the same for FileTransfer and getAbsolutePath - yet the file doesn't exist.  Once I figure out why the file doesn't exist, I'll look into the exception.

Comment: Does it really exist?  In my IDE, I can browse the device, or use ADB or use root explorer.  I think confirmation that it exists, where you think it does, is the key.

Comment: @simon, solved but I can't accept the answer for 2 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, somewhere there is a bug.  I'm inclined to believe it's a bug in getAbsolutePath() because I'm seeing consistent operation elsewhere.

When I create the "File update" variable, then immediately test and log the update.getAbsolutePath() - it shows the correct path.  But when I attempt to create the FileInputStream, the path is different (+ /files/)

So, a little searching and I found that in order to access the application data directory (without /files) I must send a different directory with the new File command.  Here's what it looks like:

```
File update = new File(ctx.getApplicationInfo().dataDir,"update.zip");
```

Obtaining the dir with getFilesDir()

```
ctx.getFilesDir() = /data/data/com.yadda.yadda/files
```

Obtaining the correct dir

```
ctx.getApplicationInfo().dataDir = /data/data/com.yadda.yadda
```